Elastic search query upgrade from V6 to V8
So I was doing this elastic search upgrade from v6.4.2 to v8.1.5 and got stuck with a Sort section of the query below.
   var search = new SearchDescriptor<Models.LexAnalysis>()
    .Query(q => query)
    .From(searchParams.KeepResults ? searchParams.PageNum * searchParams.PageSize : 0)
    .Size(searchParams.KeepResults ? searchParams.PageSize : 0)
    .Sort(sort => sort
        .Field(sf => sf
            .Order(searchParams.SortDirection == (int)LexSortDirection.Ascending ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending)
            .Field(new Field("data.id"))
            .UnmappedType(sortType)
            .Nested(nsf => nsf
                .Path(x => x.Data)
                .Filter(fil => fil
                    .Term(tf => tf
                        .Field("data.qSKey")
                        .Value(searchParams.SortColKey)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
);

I searched a lot and was able to change some of the syntaxes as below.
void search(SearchRequestDescriptor<Models.LexAnalysis> s) => s
.From(searchParams.KeepResults ? searchParams.PageNum * searchParams.PageSize : 0)
.Size(searchParams.KeepResults ? searchParams.PageSize : 0)
.Query(query)
.Sort(sort => sort
        .Field(new Field("data_id"))
        .Order(searchParams.SortDirection == (int)LexSortDirection.Ascending ? SortOrder.Asc : SortOrder.Desc)
        .UnmappedType(sortType)
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path("data")
            .Filter(f => f
                .Term(t => t
                    .Field("data_qSKey")
                    .Value(searchParams.SortColKey)
            )
        )
    )
);

I appreciate any help to get this fixed as the SearchRequestDescriptor model only contains a property for Field.
